# Elasticsearch: Replacement for Fuzzy Like This Query Deprecation

Tags: elasticsearch

Reference to this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-flt-query.html) it said that the Fuzzy Like This (also Fuzzy Like This Query) will be deprecated in ES version > 1.6, and completely remove in version 2.
I'm using Elasticsearch version 1.5.1 and using a lot of FLT statement in my search query. I would like to upgrade the ES version to the current latest (1.7), but I could not find any suggest about FLT replacement when move to newer version? So I would like to ask, if any. And is it possible to use it when it is deprecated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the following recommendation in the [Elasticseach reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-flt-query.html)
:

> The fuzzy_like_this or flt query has been removed. Instead use the [fuzziness parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/common-options.html#fuzziness) with the [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-match-query.html?q=match%20quer) or the [More Like This Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-mlt-query.html).

Deprecated means that you can still use this feature without issues as long as you don't upgrade to version 2 or higher. I'm using version 1.7.1 and flt works fine. But the feature will no longer exist in version 2.x. For more details why they decided to remove it you can have a look at the [relevant github thread](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/10391).

Answer (score 3):

I've run into the same problem.  I borrowed a solution discussed on github https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/10391

```
{ 
    "multi_match" : {  
        "fields" : ["_all"],
        "query" : "your search text",
        "fuzziness" : "AUTO"}
}
```

multi_match has a number of other parameters you can use to improve the result.

Comment: Thanks for the example :)